# Transaction stuck because of low gas price

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, nonce, txpool

i accidentally put the lowest gas price possible when i am about to send my eth.. is there any way to cancel / re-make my transaction??

i have read some articles telling that i should out-gassed my ether scan tx once.
here is my TX 0x7d4ca2478225e3e496b0e5e2b31a7baa2761954cb4db81355f81c74181f4efea..
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7d4ca2478225e3e496b0e5e2b31a7baa2761954cb4db81355f81c74181f4efea

Comment: Are you using MetaMask?

Comment: Yes, use the same nonce and a higher gas-price.

Comment: And BTW, you've used a gas-price of 4gwei, which is most certainly not the lowest possible. For example, 3.9999gwei is lower, and so are 1000wei, 1wei and 0.

Comment: i am using my ledger nano S... i couldn't find my nonce.. it is 0.. or i should put 0 nonce in it?

Comment: It's 0 according to etherscan, so yes.

Comment: I dont mean to hijack your thread but my question is very similar. Im sending SNX from Metamask, 29.59 Gwei (which it warned me was extremely low) but its been 3 days which im not sure is normal. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2895be03a8be8b91d92d688fce4262a2d063575a96456625fa5441f5477318ce Hopefully somebody here can let me know if I should just wait longer?

Comment: Always check out current avg gas prices on Etherscan or ETH Gas station. The network is heavily used lately and <30 seems like a very low fee. Try to aim for the avg fee/gas price or at least close to safeLow

Answer (score 11):

Looking at your transaction, you have set a gas price of 4 gwei.
Though not very high for current traffic, this should eventually get picked up.
You can check gas prices and traffic on [ETH Gas watch](https://ethgas.watch/). That could help you decide if you want to pay a lower fee and wait longer for your transaction to be mined, or pay a higher fee to include it faster.

If it's not urgent and you don't mind, you can leave your transaction pending and wait for it to be mined. The estimated confirmation time according to Etherscan currently is +18 hrs. Although my experience is that it's usually quicker.

Keep in mind that future transactions, with a higher nonce, will remain pending too until the first one is approved. Transactions with a higher nonce can't be mined as you can't skip a nonce.

If you want to speed things up, you can either 'replace' or 'cancel' your original transaction by using the same nonce. Most wallets, such as Metamask, MyEtherWallet or MyCrypto support this.

### Replace

Re-submit your original transaction with the same nonce (your current nonce is: 0) and a higher gas price. Check out a 'safe gas price' on [ETH Gas watch](https://ethgas.watch/).
This will create a new transaction and will overwrite the first one, once it gets mined.

### Cancel

Create a new transaction, to send 0 ETH to your own address, with the same nonce (your current nonce is: 0) and a higher gas price. Check out a 'safe gas price' on [ETH Gas watch](https://ethgas.watch/).

This creates a new transaction and prevents previous from being mined, basically canceling the transaction. This is recommended as it is not guaranteed that the second transaction will be mined first and invalidating your first. So you could end up with your original transaction being mined first.

Comment: I also heard that there is 3rd solution - without need to update `nonce`. And so: Creating new transaction with high gas and so miners might be interested in that, and so they need to mine also previous (stuck). I didn't tested this assumption but this might theoretically work.

Comment: Just found out about another alternative https://cancel-ethereum-transactions.web.app/

Comment: @Jurosh this mechanism exists in Bitcoin, but I don't think it's present in Ethereum